# Pass the value of a variable as an argument to a command in GDB

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I have been trying to pass a value which is stored in a variable called `$filename` to `dump binary memory` command in gdb.

This is the snippet I am having trouble with:

```
set $start = table[0].mem_ptr
set $lenght = table[0].mem_ptr + table[0].mem_len
set $filename = table[0].fname

dump binary memory $filename $start $lenght
```

since the 2nd ($start) and the 3rd ($lenght) arguments of the `dump binary memory` command are numeric values, I'm not having any issue with just passing variables `$start` and `$lenght` as how I did in the snippet.

But the problem is the first argument of the command is suppose to be a string. Let's say the content of the variable `$filename` is **temp.bin**. I store the file name into the variable `$filename` and pass it to the command. In this case I am expecting `dump binary memory` command to create file temp.bin and write the content respectively into the file. The command writes the correct values into the file but it creates and names file as **$filename** not as **temp.bin**.

---

what I was trying is:

`dump binary memory eval "p $filename" $start $lenght`

but then gdb returns `Unterminated string in expression.` error.

I do not know how else I can treat this part of the command so it can place there the string I store in the variable.

---

If it could be useful, this is the output of `show version` command:

```
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 7.6.0.20140529-cvs
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was just keep trying and found the solution quickly :D

this helped me to figure it out:

```
eval "dump binary memory %s $start $lenght", $filename
```